# how to schedule task with python using Schedule?

Tags: python, time, pycharm, days, reminders

Right now i am trying to do a reminder in python with scheduler. I used the `schedule.every().tuesday.at("21:35").do(reminder)` method but i want users to input the day and time instead of setting in coding. is there a way to do so?
coding:

```
remind = input("What should i remind about?")

DAY = input("Which Day?")
Time = input("Time?")


schedule.every().(DAY).at(Time).do(print(remind))
while True:
        
    schedule.run_pending()
```

Comment: Have you check the "When NOT to use Schedule" https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#when-not-to-use-schedule
It works well for short time schedules but not recommended for ones of several days because you have no persistence in case your script crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
user_input = input("Enter a date")
# do whatever you want with the input
print(user_input)
```

You should consider extracting the day and the time from the input. It depends on how you want them.